# Is there a nice way to write Navier-Stokes equations in exterior calculus

Tags: differential-geometry, navier-stokes

I'm considering to study some high-dimensional Navier-Stokes equations. One problem is to do write the viscous equation for vorticity, helicity and other conserved quantities. I think it might be better if it is possible to work with differential form and exterior calculus? Is there any reference that I may find somewhere?

Comment: You mean in a form other than $\rho (\partial_t + v \cdot \nabla) v= f+ \dot{\overline \sigma}(\dot \nabla)$? Or formulas for the quantities you mention?

Answer (score 5):

[MS Mohamed et al](http://arxiv.org/abs/1508.01166) begin with a "standard vector calculus formulation of the NS equations",

$$
\frac{∂ \bf u}{∂ t} - \mu ∆ {\bf u} + ({\bf u} \cdot \nabla) {\bf u} + \nabla p = 0
$$
$$
\nabla \cdot {\bf u} = 0
$$

and use the rotational form,

$$
\frac{∂ \bf{u}}{∂ t} + \mu \nabla \times \nabla \times {\bf u} - {\bf u}\times(\nabla \times {\bf u}) + \nabla p^d = 0
$$

to eventually derive

$$
\frac{∂ {\bf u}^\flat}{∂ t} + (-1)^{N+1} \mu \star d \star d {\bf u}^\flat + (-1)^{N+2}\star ({\bf u}^\flat \wedge \star d{\bf u}^\flat) + d p^d = 0,
$$
$$
\star d \star {\bf u}^\flat = 0
$$

But they also later derive it as

$$
\frac{∂ d {\bf u}^\flat}{∂ t} + (-1)^{N+1} \mu d \star d \star d {\bf u}^\flat + (-1)^{N}d\star({\bf u}^\flat \wedge \star d{\bf u}^\flat) = 0,
$$

Judging from the stars, -1s, and flats, these results could probably be simplified by substitution of the codifferential operator $d^\dagger$. Both are also the rotational form; I would rather provide a convective form, but I'm unaware of such a derivation in the literature.

I urge Troy to actually post an answer rather than referring us to his book, but lacking the points I cannot leave a comment to that effect.

Comment: Troy Story's article is available at https://www.researchgate.net/publication/239839335_NAVIER-STOKES_DYNAMICS_ON_A_DIFFERENTIAL_ONE-FORM. Thanks for mentioning him in your post.